# Sorting by numbers and string

Tags: python, sorting

Say I have a list

```py
['1','2','20', '5', 'undefined', '4']
```

How do is sort by numbers and put undefined the last? To like this?

```py
['1','2','4', '5', '20', 'undefined']
```

```
dirnames.sort(key=int)
```

This only works without 'undefined'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dirnames.sort(key=lambda s: [1] if s == 'undefined' else [0, int(s)])
```

or

```
dirnames.sort(key=lambda s: float('inf') if s == 'undefined' else int(s))
```

Comment: could u explain the first line of code? what is [1]?

Comment: A list with one element, the number `1`.